# Problem exporting shp to CAD with ArcMap 10.4 - all features export to layer 0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, cad, dwg, arcgis-10.4

I am finding trouble when using the tool to export shapefiles to dwg when using arcmap 10.4.

After using the tool to create CAD fields, I name the fields "Layer" and "RefName" the same way, and set the value of the field LyrOn to 1. As far as I know this is the requirement to create a CAD layer when exporting from arc to dwg.

[image: Data view of layers to convert]
[image: Attribute table 1 - layer and refname]
[image: Attribute table 2 - lyrOn]

When running the conversion tool no error messages appear and all seems to go nicely, but when I open the dwg, all the features have exported onto Layer0, and none of the layers specified in the "Layer" and "RefName" fields of the shapefiles appear.

If I use a seedfile where the layers are specified beforehand, the conversion will go alright, but whatever is not specificed in the seedfile, will go automatically to Layer 0.

[image: Data View - CAD]
[image: Attribute table - CAD]

Before upgrading to version 10.4, whatever wasn't in the seedfile would not export to CAD at all - now it does onto Layer0, so I guess it's progress. 
However, clearly something is wrong and I don't quite get what it is.

Comment: Why don't you just directly import your shapefile into CAD? You will retain all of your fields then.

Comment: I now tested export from Shapefile to DWG on ArcGIS 10.4.1, as you write, and work it without any problem. I use attribute Layer,C,9 or LYRNAME,C,254 and both is positive with char like "A-Z" "0-9" "empty space" "_".

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is here:  https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008886

I was having the same exact problem and this quick fix helped resolve my problem. Essentially, you gotta create a field called "Elevation" of type Double, then populate it with your contour or elevation results... Then the exporting to CAD from shapefile works perfectly and the elevation field will be filled out.